C++ Convert byte (unsigned char) to hexadecimal string
I have a piece of code here :
    unsigned char a = 0xF1;
    std::stringstream hexStr;
    hexStr << hex << a;
    string b = hexStr.str();
    cout << b << endl;

Which outputs plusorminus char/string to command line.
I want b to be "F1".

The output stream operator << will treat all character types as characters. If you want to output its actual value you need to explicitly convert it to another type, like hexStr << hex << static_cast<unsigned>(a);

On a different note, in your example will you use b somewhere else? Or are you just doing this for output? If only for output, then there's no need for the string stream or b, and you can write directly to std::cout.

Your code only has a small mistake. std::hex only works with int data types, that means you need to cast a into an int or other int data types when inserting it into the stringstream.
unsigned char a = 0xF1;
std::stringstream hexStr;
hexStr << hex << static_cast<int>(a);
string b = hexStr.str();
cout << b << endl;


"std::hex only works with int" - this is not entirly correct. It also works with types like short, unsigned int and other integral types (but you are right that it does not affect chars).

The explanation is not correct. This also doesn't explain why OP's code was not working and why/how using static_cast solves the problem.

you're right, thanks for the clarification

@user12002570 OP's code wasn't working because he was trying to insert a 'char' directly into the stream which it can't read. By using static_cast<int>(a) insures that a can be correctly handled by the compiler

@RazvanTivadar That is not explanation but only translation of the code. What/why is the problem in inserting a char into the stream? Why/how inserting int isn't a problem. Why casting it to int gives the desired output?

@user12002570 I'm not really sure why, but that's what the documentation says https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/#:~:text=When%20basefield%20is%20set%20to%20hex%2C%20integer%20values%20inserted%20into%20the%20stream%20are%20expressed%20in%20hexadecimal%20base%20(i.e.%2C%20radix%2016). It probably has to do with the fact that even though char is essentially an integer, the stream still sees it as a character. That means that if you don't cast it to an int, what will be inserted in the stream will be the character itself, not its numerical value

All std::hex does is that it sets the basefield of the stream to hexadecimal. This means that you will now use hexadecimal base system of counting for integer I/O.
This doesn’t affect character I/O. Characters will still be represented in their default format while integers will be represented in hexadecimal format. std::hex is simply an I/O manipulator.
If you want to output an integer in hexadecimal format, use std::hex. unsigned chars are not integers. [1][2]

unsigned char a = 0xF1;
IOStream << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(a) << std::endl;

[1] DO NOT confuse with reinterpreting the binary representation of one type as another type.
[2] This does not mean that you cannot reinterpret an unsigned char as an int just as reinterpreting an std::byte, double e.t.c as int.
